# jinja groupby with iteritems()

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

I have a dictionary

```
a:
    attr1: abc
    attr2: fddf
b:
    attr1: abc
    attr2: djfkdjf
...
```

I want to group by 'attr1'. I know I can do the following

```
{% for grouper in mydict.values()|groupby('attr1') %}
   something
{% endfor %}
```

But this is not what I want, because when I use values(), I lose the keys.

I need to use iteritems(), but it returns a list of tuples, which won't work with groupby

Answer (score 2):

I believe that `dict2items | groupby('value.attr1')` will do what you want, although due to the lack of `items2dict`, you'll have to glue the "value" side of the answer back together by hand:

```
- set_fact:
    reassembled: |
      {% for grouper in (mydict | dict2items | groupby('value.attr1')) %}
      {% set a_key = grouper[0] %}
      {% set d = dict() %}
      {% for it in grouper[1] %}
      {%   set _ = d.update({it["key"]: it["value"]}) %}
      {% endfor %}
      the key = {{ a_key }} and d={{ d }}
      {% endfor %}
```

I'll wait patiently for techraf to point out the more succinct way of doing that, but since no one else was chiming in, I thought I'd take a stab at it.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that groupby supports index. Instead of values() use items()

I achieved it by this

```
{% for grouper in mydict.items()|groupby('1.attr1') %} 
   something 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: note the difference between values() and items(); values() returns something like [{attr1: abc, attr2: fddf}, {attr1: abc, attr2: djfkdjf}] while items return [(a, {attr1: abc, attr2: fddf}), (b, {attr1: abc, attr2: djfkdjf})], so you'll need to group by a child attribute, but here you can't specify the child attribute because you don't know the parent's name